# Can't generate html page into pdf with wkhtmltopdf in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pdf-generation, thymeleaf, wkhtmltopdf

In my recent spring project, I need to generate a pdf file from html page. I am trying to do this task with `WkhtmlToPdf`. But i am unable to generate pdf file from html page. I search many project and tutorial about `WkhtmlToPdf` but I didn't find any answer. I am posting my code here.
This is my Controller class that redirect to html page with student list

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    PdfDemo pdfDemo;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    private String testPage(Model model)
    {    
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.findAll();
        System.out.println(studentList);
       model.addAttribute(studentList);
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

This is my html page that show list of student

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="pdfDiv">
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Session</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Roll</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="student : ${studentList}">
            <td th:text="${student.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.session}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.department}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.roll}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.mobile}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="#" th:href="@{/getStudentsListAsPdf}">Download PDF</a>
</body>
```

Here you can see, I have a link to generate pdf. The `PdfGenerateController` class is

```
@Controller
public class PdfGenerateController {

    @GetMapping("/getStudentsListAsPdf")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> generateReportOfStudent() {

        String downloadFilePath = generatePdfListForStudents();
        System.out.println("DL File Path: "+downloadFilePath);
        if (downloadFilePath == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("data missing");

        if (downloadFilePath == null)
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                    .body(null);

        File file = new File(downloadFilePath);

        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayResource resource = null;
        try {
            resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"student_list" + ".pdf\"");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(resource);
    }
}
```

And this is the class  where code are written to generate pdf

```
@Service
public class PdfDemo {

    @Value("${file.download.base}")
    private String DOWNLOAD_FOLDER;

    public static final String DOWNLOAD_PATH = "tmp/downloads/";
    public static final String ZIP_PATH = "/tmp/zip_files";
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "student_list";
    public static final String SERVER_REPORT_URL = "/report/html";
    public static final String DOWNLOAD_FILE_PATH = DOWNLOAD_PATH + FILE_NAME;
    public static final String ZIPFILE = "/tmp/zip_files/cmed_report.zip";
    public static final String ZIPFILE_NAME = "cmed_report.zip";
    public static final String SRCDIR = "/tmp/downloads";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH";

    public static String getBaseURL() throws MalformedURLException {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        String baseUrl = "";
        if (request != null) {
            // handle proxy forward
            String scheme = request.getScheme();
            if (request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto") != null) {
                scheme = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto");
            }

            Integer serverPort = request.getServerPort();
            if ((serverPort == 80) || (serverPort == 443)) {
                // No need to add the server port for standard HTTP and HTTPS ports, the scheme will help determine it.
                baseUrl = String.format("%s://%s%s", scheme, request.getServerName(), request.getContextPath());
            } else {
                baseUrl = String.format("%s://%s:%d%s", scheme, request.getServerName(), serverPort, request.getContextPath());
            }
        }

        return baseUrl;
    }

    public static String generatePdfListForStudents()
    {
        WkHtmlToPdf pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf();


        try {
            pdf.addSources(Source.fromUrl(getServerAbsolutePath(SERVER_REPORT_URL)));

            System.out.println("Server absolute path: " + getServerAbsolutePath(SERVER_REPORT_URL));
            System.out.println(Source.fromUrl(getServerAbsolutePath(SERVER_REPORT_URL)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String downloadPath = DOWNLOAD_FILE_PATH + ".pdf";

        pdf.addArguments(
                Argument.from(EnableJavascript));

        System.out.println("PDF Location: " + downloadPath);
        // Save the PDF
        File file = new File(downloadPath);
        System.out.println("Directory status: " + file.exists() + " " + file.isDirectory());

        try {
            System.out.println("Paths.get: " + Paths.get(downloadPath));

            pdf.save(Paths.get(downloadPath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return downloadPath;
    }

    public static String getServerAbsolutePath(String requestPath) throws MalformedURLException {
        String URL = getBaseURL() + requestPath;
        return URL;
    }
}
```

And this is the `Controller` class for `SERVER_REPORT_URL` in `PdfDemo` class

```
@Controller
public class HtmlViewReportController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;


    @GetMapping(value = "/report/html")
    public String getPdfReportForStudent(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("studentList", studentService.findAll());
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

Now, When I hit on `Download PDF`in html page I get `error`. Error stack trace here

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)
    at com.ztomic.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf.convert(WkHtmlToPdf.java:84)
    at com.ztomic.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf.getPdfBytes(WkHtmlToPdf.java:77)
    at com.ztomic.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf.save(WkHtmlToPdf.java:68)
    at com.avijit.test.PdfUtil.PdfDemo.generatePdfListForStudents(PdfDemo.java:109)
    at com.avijit.test.Controller.PdfGenerateController.generateReportOfStudent(PdfGenerateController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 71 more
DL File Path: tmp/downloads/student_list.pdf
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/dracula/IdeaProjects/WkhtmlToPdfGeneratorProject/tmp/downloads/student_list.pdf
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at com.avijit.test.Controller.PdfGenerateController.generateReportOfStudent(PdfGenerateController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here the github [link](https://github.com/AaviJit/HtmlToPdfWithWkhtmltoPdf). It will be very helpful if any one can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. It took a long time to solve. I wrote a blog step by step in the medium. Here I am posting that link. You can see all the steps here. I also provided github link of sample project. Look 
[here](https://medium.com/@avijitbarua/generate-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-at-spring-boot-project-in-ubuntu-cb0a69a1cdf8)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install wkhtmltopdf in your machine ? try it on https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

I did it in a simpler way using Pdf Object from

```
import com.github.jhonnymertz.wkhtmltopdf.wrapper.Pdf;
```

The generation of pdf looks easier as follows:

```
@Override
public String save(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
    pdf.addPageFromUrl(url);
    return mockSaveS3(pdf);
}

private String mockSaveS3(Pdf pdf) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    File fileTemp = File.createTempFile("pdf-", "");
    File file = pdf.saveAs("apps/" + fileTemp.getName());
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

And I returned the Url to the PDF that I stored in `apps/` directory.